# Forwarding remote port 80 to OSX Localhost port

Tags: macos, ssh, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

I've created SSH tunnels in the past, but I'm having trouble on OSX. I'm looking to take a website's port 80, and direct it to my localhost:8080 (or whatever port, really). When I run this command

```
sudo ssh -v -L 8080:<cloud_ip_address>:80 root@<cloud_ip_address> -N
```

I get the default apache 'it works!' page... But not the actual port 80 web page.

I also tried this variation, which gave me the same results:

```
sudo ssh -v -L localhost:8080:<cloud_ip_address>:80 root@<cloud_ip_address> -N
```

Why am I not getting the the typical html page of the remote machine (which is running a web app)?

**UPDATE:**

```
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:~ marcleonard$ sudo ssh -vvv -L 8080:<cloud_ip_address>:80 root@<cloud_ip_address> -N
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <cloud_ip_address> [<cloud_ip_address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "<cloud_ip_address>" from file "/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 174/320
debug2: bits set: 999/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 2f:d2:b7:da:39:7b:97:04:f6:56:ae:fe:b8:31:ae:79
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "<cloud_ip_address>" from file "/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '<cloud_ip_address>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug2: bits set: 1015/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/marcleonard/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7febaa50c7d0),
debug2: key: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/marcleonard/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 02:65:81:cd:7e:72:21:f6:01:3f:87:8d:10:c9:49:7c
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 02:65:81:cd:7e:72:21:f6:01:3f:87:8d:10:c9:49:7c
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <cloud_ip_address> ([<cloud_ip_address>]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8080 forwarded to remote address <cloud_ip_address>:80
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 5 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

Comment: Please execute `ssh -vvv -L 8080:<cloud_ip_address>:80 root@<cloud_ip_address> -N` and post output. It is possible that you actually have apache running on your localhost:8080 and you see this one instead of the one you are trying to redirect. You can easly check that by trying to forward different port, e.g `localhost:7979`

Comment: My answer on [SO is not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711596/osx-ssh-tunnel-from-remote-port-to-local/41714541#41714541)?

Comment: @Jakuje no, as OSX seems to have potentially obscured some of the typical SSH functions. Your response was great, I just think I posted it in the wrong SO forum :-)

Comment: @running.t see update...